# Access component property in View

Tags: ember.js

I have a `component` that calls a `view`.  Inside the `view`, I'd like to access a property on the `component` in the `view`'s handlebars template.  Is there a way to do that?  I've tried accessing it directly, but just using `{{propertyName}}`, but that results an `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`  error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View inherits the component context, below a working example available [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hotaf/1/edit):

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="views/person">
    Inside View: {{name}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/app-person">
    Component: {{name}}<br/>
    {{view App.PersonView}}
  </script>
```

Comment: You are indeed correct. Unfortunately, it still doesnt work. I actually have a view in a view in a component and its the second nested view that isnt inheriting the property.

Comment: could you setup an http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ demo using your current ember version?